# Issues with TRMM nc4 plotting with python3

Tags: python, matplotlib, netcdf4

I tried to plot this TRMM data and it was empty. 
A few things:

1. I have (and have been using) *.nc file of TRMM monthly mean data and it was fine.
2. I downloaded daily TRMM data recently and they are all in *.nc4 extension. And its Lon and Lat seem flipped : (pcp,lon,lat) instead of (pcp, lat, lon) or something similar.
3. I can plot the old TRMM files (*.nc) but when I use the same script for *.nc4, it's not
   working.

Here is my code (ignore the unused libraries):

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
from pylab import *

f1 = nc.Dataset('3B42_Daily.20030925.7.nc4.nc4')

pcpt1 = f1.variables['precipitation'][:,:]
pcpt1 = pcpt1*24
print (pcpt1.shape)

lon = f1.variables['lon'][:]
lat = f1.variables['lat'][:]


fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.08,bottom=0.15)
map = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat= 0,urcrnrlat=15,llcrnrlon=90.,urcrnrlon=120,resolution='i')
x,y=np.meshgrid(lat,lon)
cs = map.contourf(x,y,pcpt1)
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawcountries()
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,90.,3),labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=9,linewidth=0.1)
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,3),labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=9,linewidth=0.1)
plt.title('Precipitation TRMM',fontsize=10)

cax = fig.add_axes([0.015,0.,0.80,0.02])#0.015,0.25,0.97,0.02])
aa=fig.colorbar(cs,cax=cax,orientation='horizontal',format='%0.1f')
aa.set_label('mm/hr',fontsize=10)
aa.ax.tick_params(labelsize=7) 
plt.show()
```

The data is small, here:

[TRMM data temporary location](https://tmpfiles.org/download/35130/3B42_Daily.20030925.7.nc4.nc4)

[(Use this link if the link above expired)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lj5s5r671xbzhkr/3B42_Daily.20030925.7.nc4.nc4?dl=0)

So, here what I got when I ran the script (nothing unusual, but I got an empty plot):

```
In [39]: runfile('/Users/fadzilnor/fmonorovgmail/a-ANALYSIS/py/casestudy_percentile/trmm_nc4_test.py', wdir='/Users/fadzilnor/fmonorovgmail/a-ANALYSIS/py/casestudy_percentile')
(1440, 400)
/Users/fadzilnor/fmonorovgmail/a-ANALYSIS/py/casestudy_percentile/trmm_nc4_test.py:62: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The dedent function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3. Use inspect.cleandoc instead.
  map = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat= 0,urcrnrlat=15,llcrnrlon=90.,urcrnrlon=120,resolution='i')
/Users/fadzilnor/fmonorovgmail/a-ANALYSIS/py/casestudy_percentile/trmm_nc4_test.py:69: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The dedent function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3. Use inspect.cleandoc instead.
  map.drawcountries()
```

[image: empty plot]

I suspect the Lon and Lat issue (of their weird dimension?)

Comment: OK, I've experimented on something and map.contourf(y,x,pcpt1) works instead of map.contourf(x,y,pcpt1). I need to check further on this.